# Search For ID number In TextFile vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is what i need to do, I click on the openfile button and brings up the openfile dialog box. I open a textfile and it gets displayed in the informationbox.text field, at the same time i would like to search that file for an ID number and display it in the IDbox.text field. 
i have searched other forums, but they just use the **Replace** method or other methods that i don't know about. It becomes too confusing.

This is what i have so far -

```
  Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim oReader As StreamReader
    OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        oReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, True)
        InformationBox.Text = oReader.ReadToEnd
        My.Forms.Home.TextBox5.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Opened Customer : " & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & " File")
        oReader.Close()
    End If
    IDBox.Text = ""
    Label11.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
End Sub
```

example of textfile :

Name of customer       : Name

Surname of customer  :Surname

ID number                   : 12345678910

Record number           : 001

Address of Customer   : Address

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please show an example of such a text file. How is the ID exactly stored in the file?

Comment: added that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code you use `StreamReader` to read the text file.

The "drawback" of Streams is that you have to manage their disposing manually.
In your example, if an error occurs in `oReader.ReadToEnd` the line `oReader.Close` will not be hit and the Stream might remain undisposed thus causing trouble.
So you´d better enclosure your Stream in a `Using` scope (another option would be to use static `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines|ReadAllText` methods).

```
 Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
   'Dim oReader As StreamReader <-- DELETE THIS
    OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
   If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
      'MY CODE STARTS HERE:
      Dim customerInfo As String
      Using sr = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, True)
            customerInfo = sr.ReadToEnd()
      End Using 'Close the stream early since we have all data needed

     'Write all lines into a string array
      Dim lines As String() = customerInfo.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     'Get the line where the ID Number is in
      Dim idLine As String = lines.Where(Function(l) l.StartsWith("ID number")).FirstOrDefault()
      Dim id As String = String.Empty
      If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(idLine) Then
         Dim aIdLine() = idLine.Split(":"c) 'Split the ID line by :
         If aIdLine.Length >= 1 Then
             id = aIdLine(1) 'This should be the actual ID
         End If
      End If

  'Set UI
   My.Forms.Home.TextBox5.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Opened Customer : " & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & " File")
   InformationBox.Text = customerInfo
   IDBox.Text = id
   Label11.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
 End If
```

Comment: I copied your code, and i tried it out, nothing happens in the IDBox.text field. The informationbox.text field was populated with text, which is fine. No errors appeared either

Comment: Can you [upload](http://textuploader.com/) your textfile you are testing with please? There might be a mismatch between mine and yours since it was working for me. In the meantime: Debug my code and check `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(idLine) Then` is true or false. If true also check  `If aIdLine.Length >= 1 Then` is true or false.

Comment: how do i upload my txt file?

Comment: strange it works for me. I will upload my whole project which you can compare to yours.

Comment: Donwload my code [here](https://github.com/mistalan/Customer) (GitHub). I used Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6.1 but you can change it if you use other versions.